# how to find out the server where the site is located

Tags: server, dns, ip-address

explain me please, how to find out the server where the ip address of site is located?

I understand so...
1.when in browser we write domain of website(for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)), the browser send that name to DNS server. DNS server find the ip address of that domain and send it to browser. the browser makes a request with that ip address and now the question arises - how to find out which server that ip address is on?

if this question is wrong, so another question is..

2.if this ip address is the server ip address, so how the required site is located on the server, because there can be many sites in one server.

Answer (score 0):

This role is played by layer 3 and above networking devices. For example router, firewalls etc.

When a new web-server is added, web-server administrator adds routes which are advertised to all over. When you are trying to reach that specific web-server, your router checks the route for that server IP address.

You can login into your router and check the routes. If you are not authorized to login the router then you can find it easily with the help of trace-route command from your laptop.

Refer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up3bcBLZS74

Refer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bIpUup5Vp4